# How to show attachments in Lightning knowledge

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

Referring below post:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009CyyIAE

I came to know I can display knowledge articles like attachment like this  in classic

```
<apex:outputLink value="/servlet/fileField?entityId= {!FAQ__kav.Id}&field=Attachment_1__Body__s">
<apex:outputfield value="{!FAQ__kav.Attachment_1__Name__s}"/>
</apex:outputLink>
```

How can I do it Lightning Knowledge. How can I display attachments in Lightning.

I read below documents:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_compare_classic_lightning.htm&type=5

For Lightning Knowledge:

> Files are stored in the standard Files Object and attached in the files related list

i Need to use salesforce files(that content version).how can I filter it based on knowledge Id

Comment: Yes but I need to filter it based on Knowledge Id how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to query `ContentDocumentLink` table for  `ContentDocumentId` by passing your knowledge id as LinkedEntityId

eg:

```
SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId ='ka01l0000008SflAAE'
```

And the url to view it will be

```
https://instanceurl.salesforce.com/lightning/r/ContentDocument/ContentDocumentId/view
```